# Integral bounds of $−1 < z < 1$?

Tags: integration

Find the electric field flux
$$ \Phi_E=\int \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{a} $$
through the cylindrical surface $s=1.5$, $-1<z<1$.

So I'm doing a double integral with respect to $\theta$ and $z$, but $z$ is less than $1$ and bigger than $-1$. Wondering if I can still sub in $1$ and $-1$ for my bounds or do I choose numbers like $0.9$, $-0.9$ as there is no less than or equal to sign present?

Comment: What's $s$ here?

Comment: It's the radius of a cylinder, and z is the cylinder length, I just want to know what the bounds of z would be in definite integral because it says z is < 1 and > -1 but not >= or <=.